# Где в Windows хранятся пути ко всем файлам установленной программы?

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система

Где в Windows(10) у установленных программ хранятся пути ко всем ее составляющим файлам? Допустим,когда мы деинсталлируем какую-то программу,uninstall.exe удаляет все файлы данной программы,которые могут находиться в совершенно разных директориях. В каком файле(?) хранится список путей составных компонентов программы(то есть всех файлов,из которых состоит сама программа) или иными словами,откуда unistall.exe узнает где находятся файлы,которые нужно удалить. Например ,в Debian и Ubuntu данный список путей можно найти в `/var/lib/dpkg/*.list` ,где вместо * имя установленного пакета(программы)

Comment: Подозреваю, у каждого uninstall.exe своё уникальное место и уникальный формат, и универсального ответа не получится

Comment: @andreymal, меня скорее интересует,где находится вообще список этих путей к файлам. Unistall.exe - это просто пример. Ведь подобная информация нужна и самой программе,что бы функционировать со своими составляющими элементами, и каким-либо другим компонентам ОС(реестру и тд)

Comment: Самой программе такая информация далеко не всегда нужна, она может вычислять и подгружать нужные себе файлы динамически по конфигам или листингам каталогов (в линуксе то же самое, между прочим)

Comment: Дай угадаю. Ты захотел как-то автоматом получать список всех-всех установленных прог и по мановению волшебной палочки их удалять?

Comment: @donRumata нет, вообще мне необходимо по заданному пути к файлу определить к какому программному обеспечению он относится(где это возможно).

Comment: Ну в принципе - то же самое. Спешу огорчить - всё плохо. Потому что установщиков - зоопарк. А их версий - вообще вагон. Даже майки, которые придумали msi им не всегода пользуются. Посмотри как распространяется directx9, vcredist2017, skype7 и skype8. А потом посмотри как сделали в Autodesk. Тогда поймёшь, что овчинка выделки не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

В Windows не хранится информация о файлах отдельных программ. Определены только стандартные каталоги, такие как `AppData`. Программа сама знает свои файлы, а Uninstall удаляет то, что определено скриптом инсталлятора.

Система что-то знает только о программах, установленных через msi, но многие программы устанавливаются другими способами. Точно так же и в Линуксе не все устанавливается через менеджер пакетов.

Comment: ,откуда "программа сама знает свои файлы"? Эта же информация должна быть где-то записана?

Comment: @Martin Orlov, в программе и записана, где же еще. Систему не интересует, что она записала куда-то в `AppData` какой-нибудь `settings.xml`. Или что у нее есть какой-то dll - он записан в скрипте инсталлера, и uninstall программы про него из скрипта и знает.